# R: unwrap sublists to single list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists, where each sublist has the same number of elements with the same names; like so:

```
l <- list( list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4), list(a=5, b=6) )
```

I would like to rearrange the inner sublists *by name* such that the resulting list only has two elements, each a list, but containing all the original data i.e. I would like to obtain the following list:

```
desired_list <- list( a=list(1, 3, 5), b=list(2, 4, 6) )
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Does your list only have two levels at most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::transpose`:

```
pl <- purrr::transpose(l)

identical(desired_list, pl)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

An alernative base R method, use `do.call(Map, ...)`:

```
# pass all the sublists to the Map method, and collect them as lists 
bl <- do.call(Map, c(f=list, l))

identical(desired_list, bl)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that both of these methods require all `a` and `b` to be in the same order for each nested list? E.g. it doesn't work if your list is: `list( list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4), list( b=6, a=5) )`

Comment: In my particular case, the list elements *are* in the same order. But if it makes more sense to generalize the question and open it back up, I will.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the base R method by reading ?Map and ?do.call, but it doesn't seem trivial to see what is really happening here.

Is it the case that Map calls list on every element of l?

Comment: @MikeH. For those cases, probably need to reorder the sublists by names firstly then `lapply(l, `[`, c('a', 'b'))`.

Comment: @NLi10Me `do.call(function, vector)` will pass all the elements in the vector to the function as arguments. so in your case `do.call(Map, c(f = list, l))` can be translated to `Map(f = list, l[[1]], l[[2]], l[[3]])`, and then apply list function to all elements in the sublists in parallel. So elements at the same positions are collected as one list in the result.

Comment: It's subtle but now very clear. Thank you very much gentlemen.

Comment: @Psidom Incidentally I *did* install purrr. Is there any advantage to using it over the base method (speed or memory)?

Comment: Not sure about the speed. But I found it quite a convenient and intuitive function to use in this case.